# Box2d Body filled with a texture Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a simple triangular shape (obstacle) in my game and i would like to fill it with a texture repeatedly. I have looked at the other 2 topics but couldn't find a working solution. How can i fill this triangle with a small image (assume that its called "brickTexture.png" repeatedly?
Here is the code for creating the box2dbody of the obstacle in Obstacle.java

```
BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
bdef.position.set(obstaclePosition);
bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
PolygonShape triangle = new PolygonShape();
float vertices1[] ={-50 / PPM, 100 / PPM,
                    50 / PPM, 100 / PPM,
                     0 / PPM,  0 / PPM};
triangle.set(vertices1);

fdef.shape = triangle;
b2body.createFixture(fdef);
```

And this is the triangle

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by using the classes **PolygonRegion** and **PolygonSpriteBatch** and will work for any polygonal shape (not just triangles).

Create the polygon region:

```
// this will calculate the triangles given your vertices
short triangles[] = new EarClippingTriangulator().computeTriangles(vertices1).toArray();
// use your texture region
PolygonRegion polygonRegion = new PolygonRegion(textureRegion, vertices1, triangles);
```

Then you need to use the **PolygonSpriteBatch** to render at the desired position (I presume body position):

```
polygonSpriteBatch.draw(polygonRegion, x, y);
```

Make sure you load your texture with **Repeat** wrap so it can tile:

```
texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
```

Class docs: [PolygonRegion](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/PolygonRegion.html), [EarClippingTriangulator](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/EarClippingTriangulator.html), [PolygonSpriteBatch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/PolygonSpriteBatch.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! I got another small question if it doesn't bother, how can I change the density of the texture without changing the original file's size?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you mean with the texture density. Perhaps you mean drawing it at different sizes? If so the PolygonSpriteBatch has several draw methods with args for such needs, or maybe you want it to not look pixelated when drawing by setting the texture filter to linear: texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

Sorry for the late response probably you solved this already.

Comment: Actually what I meant was different but I get how this triangulating system works just now and it does not matter anymore. Thanks for the help a lot again. Appreciated